# How to train and test tensorflow CNN on files residing at local computer

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am new to python and tensorflow. I am trying to use a convolutional neural network algorithm implemented in tensorflow. What is need to do is to train and test my own dataset instead of MNIST dataset.
Currently program is using:

```
def main(unused_argv):
  # Load training and eval data
  mnist = tf.contrib.learn.datasets.load_dataset("mnist")
  train_data = mnist.train.images  # Returns np.array
  train_labels = np.asarray(mnist.train.labels, dtype=np.int32)
  eval_data = mnist.test.images  # Returns np.array
  eval_labels = np.asarray(mnist.test.labels, dtype=np.int32)
```

Can you please guide me how can I train and test CNN on data files mnist_test.csv  and mnist_train.csv residing at D:/datafile of my computer.

Comment: official api : https://www.tensorflow.org/api_guides/python/reading_data

Answer (score -1):

You can use the command below to train and eval the model by use of [ronnie.ai framework](http://ronnie.ai)

```
eResult = CNNModel.trainNeval(trainData, evalData, designer.modelDef, 200, 50, 1, evalSteps=1)
```